# Multiple records entry using spreadsheet

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a simple Content type "Contact List" with following fields:

1. Contact Person
2. Designation
3. Company
4. Email Address
5. Contact No

I want to create a spreadsheet-like interface for my users to past their multiple contacts on the webpage and get their entries recorded into the content type. I don't require full spread-sheet features like of "Sheetnode (http://drupal.org/project/sheetnode)", but would definitely require that the entered records are fully compliant with the content type validations (e.g. email addresses).